# How do I override the default File Picker

Tags: windows, windows-8

Most programs use windows picker. (e.g., open a file in emacs, photoshop, or browsing the installation directory).

While this is all good, some of the pickers are 'bad' - notoriously the directory picker, since it is **so freaking small** and very hard to navigate. Some also have 'niceties' while others don't have them (favorites folder, libraries, etc)

Now I want to ask if it is possible to override the pickers, so I can have a universal, easy to navigate picker whenever a dialog should appear.

Comment: I assume you are reffering to the Open file dialogs?

Comment: @KardNails Yes, I think that would be the term...

Comment: Well, as far as I know, it is not possible, as each program is responsible for its own such dialog. If there is a way not involving hacking core files, I'd be interested as well.

Comment: I'm not a Windows Programmer, but I'm taking a wild guess they're doing a call to the windows API to show the dialog, so if we can somehow override the call, then it would be possible to change it (I am open to soft that hacks the core :) )

Comment: @Secret - AFAIK it is not possible to change what API the program will use. It entirely depends on the program developer. Also, any modification is possible only if the developer keeps the code open-sourced, which will still involve compilation and such things.

Comment: @Secret - You are indeed correct you are not a Windows Programmer, and as a programmer I can tell you, while there is a standard open dialog a program can  also implement its own.  What you want is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

Ok guys I found one that enables you to change the places links in the open/save dialog. The changes are subtle, but still very useful - just having my favorites folder inside the open/save dialog saves a lot of clicks.

A way to change the links is by editing it in the registry, or using [placesbar](http://melloware.com/download/).

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/97824/how-to-customize-the-file-opensave-dialog-box-in-windows/)?

Comment: or this.  http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-default-places-bar-in-windows-common-file-dialog-box/